# Working on remote directory without local copy

Tags: pycharm

currently I managed to :
- create a local project,
- sync it with remote directory (download).
then i modify my code,
- sync back to remote directory (upload)
- commit to local GIT repo
- push to remote GIT repo.

Is it possible with current release (I just purchased profesionnal 3.4) to remove all local references (then i would avoid download/upload part) : work directly on remote directory and commit on remote GIT repo when i'm done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that's impossible...
"PyCharm does not support direct editing of files on servers"
one needs to have local copy and work on it.